# Strange effect when resizing Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have created two custom controls. A rectangle and an ellipse. I'm am able to move them by dragging with the mouse, but I also want to resize them. The rectangle resizing works fine, but resizing of the ellipse gives a strange effect. When I click on the ellipse after resizing and drag it again the ellipse looks normal again. Here the link with a gif showing what I mean by a 'strange' effect http://gyazo.com/319adb7347ed20fe28b6b93ced8744eb. How fix this effect? Also the ellipse has some white space in the corners because it's drawn in a rectangle shape, maybe there's a way to fix that too?

Control.cs

```
class Ellipse : Control
{
    Point mDown { get; set; }

    public Ellipse()
    {
        MouseDown += shape_MouseDown;
        MouseMove += shape_MouseMove;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        // Draw a black ellipse in the rectangle represented by the control.
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, Width, Height);

        //Set transparent background
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }  

    public void shape_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mDown = e.Location;
    }

    public void shape_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Location = new Point(e.X + Left - mDown.X, e.Y + Top - mDown.Y);
        }
    }

    /* Allow resizing at the bottom right corner */
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int wmNcHitTest = 0x84;
        const int htBottomLeft = 16;
        const int htBottomRight = 17;
        if (m.Msg == wmNcHitTest)
        {
            int x = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF);
            int y = (int)((m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
            Point pt = PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
            Size clientSize = ClientSize;
            if (pt.X >= clientSize.Width - 16 && pt.Y >= clientSize.Height - 16 && clientSize.Height >= 16)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)(IsMirrored ? htBottomLeft : htBottomRight);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
  } 
}
```

Form1.cs

In this way I create the `Ellipse`'s this code is from the `panel_MouseUp (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` method.

```
case Item.Ellipse:
var el = new Ellipse();
panel.Controls.Add(el);
el.Location = new Point(x, y);
el.Width = (xe - x);
el.Height = (ye - y);
break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the control to repaint itself completely when it is resized.  Set its ResizeRedraw property to true.  You also need to be careful what you do in the Paint event handler, it should never have global state side-effects.  As written, your control promptly crashed the designer when I tried it.

Remove the last 2 lines from OnPaint and make your constructor look like this:

```
public Ellipse() {
    MouseDown += shape_MouseDown;
    MouseMove += shape_MouseMove;
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.ResizeRedraw = true;
}
```

Further improve this by overriding OnMouseDown/Move() instead of using the events.  And look at ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle() to make the resizing a bit more intuitive.